# How do I send Syslog using Python SysLogHandler from Aws lambda to remote host?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, syslog

How do I send Syslog using Python SysLogHandler from Aws lambda to remote host?

## I want to send python logs from Aws lambda to remote server using Python SysLogHandler How can I achieve that?

**Below is my simple lambda code**

```
import json
import logging
import logging.handlers

my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address = ('96.103.2**.2**',514))
my_logger.addHandler(handler)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    my_logger.info("Info statement")
    my_logger.error("Error statement")
    my_logger.warning("Warning statement")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Using this code I don't see any logs in remote server

Answer (score 0):

I had written script long back. You can check and change accordingly. Although this is writing to local dev socket /dev/log.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
tag_name = "my-logs"
formatter = logging.Formatter(tag_name + ': %(message)s')
handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(facility = "local6", address = '/dev/log')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
my_logger.addHandler(handler)
my_logger.info('this is info')
```